# Test connection to your bot getting failed : Bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework, botconnector

My bot is working fine in all Channels,but while checking Test Connection in https://dev.botframework.com its showing following error:

> InternalServerError
>   {
>     "message": "An error has occurred.",
>     "exceptionMessage": "Authorization for Microsoft App ID b649bba7-xxx-4fe5-8e0d-xxxxx failed with status code Forbidden",
>     "exceptionType": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
>   }

If there is any Authorization Error,then it should not work in any channel right? But working in Emulator,Direct line, Web chat and Skype.

Comment: Is your bot responding to the Ping activity?  This could cause that response in the dev portal.

Comment: @Lars My bot responding to the Ping activity.

Comment: @Lars Yes,when it's hit this line     `await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync()` it's throwing above error.

Comment: Clarification. Your code should not be capturing / replying to the Ping activity.  This is handled by the SDK.